# Maven Throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, maven

Maven throws error as posted below. I am trying to get a repository from remote to mine.

```
mvn package

Could not transfer metadata org.symplifier.adk:symplifier-
adk:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to a-repository 
(sftp://git.a.com.np/home/git/gitlab/public/repo/): Cannot connect. Reason: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.symplifier.adk:symplifier-`

adk:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from sftp://git.a.com.np/home/git/gitlab/public/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 

until the update interval of a-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.symplifier.adk:symplifier-adk:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to a-repository

(sftp://git.a.com.np/home/git/gitlab/public/repo/): Cannot connect. Reason: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

My maven version is

```
mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 
2015-04-22T17:42:37+05:45)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-4-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Edit1**:

I tried forcing maven to update all repositories with my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>a-repository</id>
      <url>sftp://git.a.com.np/home/git/gitlab/public/repo/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.symplifier.adk</groupId>
      <artifactId>symplifier-adk</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Force update.

```
mvn -U package
```

**Edit2**: 
Have tried deleting the pom.lastUpdated file as well. Also, deleting the repository and retrying.

One thing different is my machine's username and the username on the remote repository is different. But it should not matter as my public key is in the remote repo and that will be used for authentication.

More so, only one package is facing this error. Let me know what is wrong.

**Update**: [This](http://pastebin.com/VkzYj2ie) is the log file.

Comment: Is this troublesome dependency the only one sourced from `sftp://git.a.com.np/home/git/gitlab/public/repo/` The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException could be from the server where you want to get this dependency

Comment: My co developers have been able to update their repository without problem, so seems like a problem at my end.

Comment: It is a secure FTP site (sftp://). Do you have the credentials to access the site?

Comment: Yes. I can access it. My public key and username are stored as credentials and I can sftp to the server.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of options.

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn` with option `-X`, it should show debug logging and possibly full stack trace. That might give a clue.

Comment: @geert3 log file has been updated.

Comment: this is a bug in http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44-1/com/jcraft/jsch/IdentityFile.java/ - AFAIKT fixed in 0.1.45. You have somewhere in your classpath a `wagon-ssh.jar` that should be upgraded.

Comment: @geert3 Please edit community wiki answer, and add what you just said, so it helps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your stack trace

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.<init>(IdentityFile.java:367)
...
```

I'd venture the guess that you're using a public/private key setup to connect and Maven can't find the location of said key-file. Have a look at your `settings.xml` and see if it differs from your coworkers', eg.

```
<server>
  <id>a-repository</id>
  <username>sraddhanjali</username>
  <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
  ...
```

Comment: My coworkers had the same settings.xml as mine. I found the problem, strange problem, and posted the solution.

Comment: this is a bug in JSch 0.1.44-1 (see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44-1/com/jcraft/jsch/IdentityFile.java/)  AFAIKT fixed in 0.1.45. It is loaded as part of `wagon-ssh.jar` somewhere on your classpath. If you  upgrade that it should also work.